# Как писать в страницы памяти linux и читать оттуда

Tags: linux, c, память, kernel, ядро

У меня есть некий драйвер, который выделяет физически непрерывную память с помощью функции

```
__get_free_pages(GFP_USER, 1);
```

Два вопроса:

1) как из ядра записать в эту память что-нибудь, чтобы это можно было потом прочитать?

2) и как потом можно, собственно, прочитать эти данные из user space, то есть обычного приложения?

Comment: используй функции с говорящими названиями `copy_to_user()`/`copy_from_user()`, но желание выделить в драйвере устройства страницу пользовательского пространства выглядит как-то очень странно...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, спасибо. На самом деле мне это нужно просто для того, чтобы проверить, что туда что-то вообще в принципе записывается, не имея на руках устройство. Возможно я это делаю вообще неправильно, буду благодарен за объяснение, как правильно.

Comment: если честно, я не особо искушён в отладке модулей ядра, поэтому советовать ничего не буду, но обычно, если данных относительно не много, то ничего проще `printk()` нет... Если много или они часто меняются, то можно создать буфер в пространстве ядра и экспортировать через [debugfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/debugfs.txt).